# Leanback focus problems

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Hello guys I'm working on application and my layout structure is as following :

```
  RelativeLayout:

   CompoundView: 

   CompoundView:
          RelativeLayout:
            Button
            Button
            RecyclerView

   BrowseFragment:
          Only rows
```

My problem is when I get to first row of browse fragment and first item in it and I want to go up *(D-PAD-UP)* to focus button it does nothing it works only when I push left *( D-PAD-LEFT)*. Anyone has solution for this ?

Comment: You should provide the content of your layout xml file, since you are using the `RelativeLayout`. This will give us a clue of the order of the components.

Comment: @dan I updated structure I don't use anything except rows inside BrowseFragment

Comment: `RelativeLayout` provides attributes like: `android:layout_alignParentTop` or `android:layout_toRightOf`, etc. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) for a complete list. That is why it is important to see what was the alignment used.

Comment: You are right RelativeLayout is causing the the trouble.When I set centerInParent on button it doesn't get any kind of focus.Is there way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was in BrowseFrameLayout for some reason and to solve this issue I had to override onFocusSearchListener and manage focus myself.

In BrowseFragment which I extended I have this method :

```
public void workaroundFocus(){
    if(getView() != null) {
        View viewToFocus  = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_to_focus);
        BrowseFrameLayout browseFrameLayout = getView().findViewById(android.support.v17.leanback.R.id.browse_frame);
        browseFrameLayout.setOnFocusSearchListener((focused, direction) -> {
            if (direction == View.FOCUS_UP) {
                return viewToFocus;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    workaroundFocus();
    /*
      Rest of the code
    */
}
```

And voila it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the `RelativeLayout` you should layout the components in the order that you would like to be navigated.

Using the `XML` attributes presented in the [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) reference document, you will be able to establish an navigation order too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reminder" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@id/times"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/times"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/done" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here the `dates` `Spinner` is below the `name` `EditText` and at left of `times` `Spinner`, the `times` component is below the `name` one and the `done` `Button` is below `times`. See the image below:

[image]

See the [Build Basic TV Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html) guide for more tv related details.

Comment: hi i am facing a similar issue where i am using a RowsSupportFragment, here the header of a row gets the focus instead of the row item

Comment: @SubhasmithThapa You should open a separate, new question, with your code details, that way you will get a proper answer.

Comment: i have opened a separate question but just wanted to try my luck.  I solved my issue with this answer. Please check. Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183099/how-to-focus-on-the-listrow-item-which-is-not-focusable-on-firestick-3rd-generat